# textarea by mistake contains part of page html

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I had a partial view rendered inside a page and it worked fine. Then I introduced a textarea control in that partial view.

The rest of the page (that should have rendered after this textarea) is rendered INSIDE this textarea, to the extent that all the rest of the page is blank and I can see the HTML that should have rendered in the view as text in this textarea.

This is my Razor:

```
@if (Model == null || (Model != null && String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.QuoteNo)))
{   
    <div id="mycomments">
    <span>my Comment</span>

     <textarea name="comments" cols="100" rows="10" />
     </div>                                             
}
```

Sorry for my formatting, but this editor doesn't show up html tags otherwise.

This partial view is rendered like this:

```
 @if (Model == null)
            {
                Html.RenderPartial("_HeaderAndPartsList", Model);
            }
```

Comment: Where are your < tags for div, span etc.  You are closing tags without having opened them.

Comment: @AliK, I opened the tags ok in my view, just that this editor doesn't show HTML code; this is why I intentionatelly wrote bad tags, as I said in my question. I also found the answer, and posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.7), the `textarea` tag requires an end tag:

```
<textarea name="comments"></textarea>
```

Also of note are that HTML tags require opening `<` brackets.  Your markup seems broken in a couple of different ways.

When debugging strange behavior in HTML markup, the *first* tool to use is [the W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org).  It would identify issues like this and provide links to the official spec for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Your textarea tag is incorrect. Try this:

```
<textarea name="comments" cols="100" rows="10"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I should have closed the textarea like this:

```
</textarea>
```

Comment: text areas should be declared thus `<textarea></textarea>` why on earth are you missing out the `<`?